# Using tabHost and go to a specific tab when I click on button in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

I want to go to a specefic tab (for example : tab 2) when I click on the button in the other activity in eclipse ! Actually , tabs in activity one and button is in the activity two .
It's my code for tabs :

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab 1");
    tab1.setIndicator("Time");
    tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);

    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab 2");
    tab2.setIndicator("Project");
    tab2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);

    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab 3");
    tab3.setIndicator("Category");
    tab3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);
```

Now how can I go to the "tab 2" tab ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Call your activty2 from activity1 with**

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Where 100 is a request Code.

**You can use this method in activity1**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)

        {
            if(requestCode==100)
            {
                //perform your action here load second tab if you get a RESULT_OK for this request code

            }


        }
```

**set result on clicking button from activity2 and finish the activity**

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finsh();
```

Comment: Thanks , but it didn't help me !

Answer (score 0):

**As mentioned you have to write code to change tab in onActivityResult section. please show your code to change the tab.
Although you can use this to change the tab**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)

        {
            if(requestCode==100)
            {
                //perform your action here load second tab if you get a RESULT_OK for this request code
             tabHost.setCurrentTab(2):

            }


        }
```